# Inject property into integration test Grails 3

Tags: grails, spock

How does one inject properties from the applicaiton.yml file into an integration test in grails 3.0 ?

For ex: I have this property in my applicaiton.yml

```
----
testing:
    defaults:
        startUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/'
----
```

In my Integration Spock test, I have the following code:

```
class WebpageRolesTestSpec extends Specification {

    def grailsApplication
    String LOGIN_URL = grailsApplication.config.getProperty('testing.defaults.startUrl')

    void "test login screen prompt"() {
         expect:
         LOGIN_URL == 'http://localhost:8080/'
    }
}
```

The exception i am getting is: Cannot get property 'config' on null object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use holders:

```
import grails.util.Holders
...
LOGIN_URL = Holders.config.testing.defaults.startUrl
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Below test works for me in Grails 3.1.1, I suppose you would need a clean app.

```
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*
import spock.lang.*

@Integration
@Rollback
class SampleSpec extends Specification {
    def grailsApplication

    void "test something"() {
        expect:"fix me"
            grailsApplication.config.getProperty('testing.defaults.startUrl') == 
                'http://localhost:8080/'
    }
}
```